# how do i configure the ubiquity installer in kubuntu 22.04?

Tags: kubuntu

I am attempting to configure the ubiquity installer in kubuntu (change the graphics, remove some things from sources.list, all of that stuff.) But I can't figure it out. Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom installer ISO?

Comment: yes, i want to create a custom kubuntu iso in cubic